# Why does this Autohotkey RegExMatch fail when used on a text file but work from a variable?

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to find out why the RegExMatch command in the code below fails when I use it on a variable read from a file. It works when I assign the file content directly to a variable within AHK.

To test this, open notepad, copy the multiline content of TableCode2 into notepad and save it as c:\temp\testtable.txt

When I run the script, the first messagebox doesn't show a match.
The second box matches. I tested this both on windows7 32bit and 64bit.

Any idea what the difference between both scenarios is and why I can't match
against the file?

```
InputTable = c:\temp\testtable.txt
FileRead, TableCode, %InputTable%

TableCode2 =
(
OBJECT Table 50093 test
{
  OBJECT-PROPERTIES
  {
    Date=22.08.13;
    Time=10:47:20;
  }
  PROPERTIES
  {
  }
  FIELDS
  {
    { 1   ;   ;test                ;Text30         }
  }
  KEYS
  {
    {    ;test                                    ;Clustered=Yes }
  }
  CODE
  {

    BEGIN
    END.
  }
}
)

Needle := "FIELDS(.*)KEYS"
Foundpos := RegExMatch(TableCode,Needle,Out)
msgbox, %Needle%`n %Out1%`n--------------%TableCode%

Foundpos := RegExMatch(TableCode2,Needle,Out)
msgbox, %Needle%`n %Out1%`n--------------%TableCode%
```

Comment: Can you show us how `TableCode` file looks ?

Comment: @Sniffer: See above. Please mark the content of TableCode2 in the code. These are the lines inside the round brackets. The first line starts with "OBJECT", the last one is "}". Open windows notepad and paste these lines into a new document. Save this as testtable.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **dot** in AHK regex matches *"any single character **which is not part of a newline (`r`n) sequence**"*.
And that's the tricky part: The newlines of a Windows text file are **`r`n** by default, whereas the bracket notation inside the code consists of **`n** characters as newlines.
Consequentially, `RegExMatch("FIELDS(.*)KEYS")` will by default stop consuming when it encounters a **`r`n**. In your example regarding the file, this is immediately after `FIELDS`, disallowing the regex to ever become true.
The variable `TableCode2` on the other hand contains not a single **`r`n** character,  allowing the regex to reach `KEYS`.
There are many possible solutions like stripping each **`r** from the file, but the probably easiest and most consistent way would be to use the simple [DotAll](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#opt_s) option. *"This causes a period (.) to match all characters including newlines (normally, it does not match newlines).*"
The resulting regex could look like this: `s)FIELDS(.*)KEYS`.

However, using regular expressions to parse something that is not a *regular language*, shouldn't be done. If you have control over the output, use a standardized format like XML or JSON. If you are parsing some kind of programming language, use the existing compiler/interpreter to parse it, and then convert it.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Alas I have no control over the output, but regex parsing should be safe enough once I start matching for "^\s\sFIELDS(.*)^\s\sKEYS" after removing all `r instead.

Comment: @576i Where does the input come from and what kind of notation is that? Also, I use `(.*?)` wherever possible, making the regex non-greedy . This avoids that another occurrence of `KEYS` messes up your output.

Comment: Nice of you to explain how it works, MCL.  You're a good man.

Comment: It's Navision source code exported from the application. The way it is formatted it is guaranteed that "^\s\sFIELDS" and "^\s\sKEYS" exist exactly once (even if the table has no keys) and each field is in a "{ ; ; ; }" structure which looks like I could parse it. The result will be pasted back into Navision so if anything goes wrong the compiler will not accept it...

Comment: @BGM Thanks a lot, dude. I believe that every answer on SO should be more than "Try this code: ...". At times, I find myself not explaining much; but frankly, sometimes I have the feeling it's not worth it. Way too often there are (especially) first timers who don't even bother to comment an answer to their questions. All the more disappointing in such moments is if someone really made an effort. Anyhow, that's way off topic here ;)